# Getting all products in a category except a subcategory

Tags: category, product-list, collection-filtering

I have a structure like this:

1. My Root Category

   - Food

     - Fixed
     - Bread
     - Milk
     - ...

This code lists out all the products in Food.

```
$category_id = 11;
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model);

foreach($collection as $_product){
...
}
```

I want to list out all the products except the ones in Fixed. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to get a list of the product ids from the "Fixed" category and add a filter to your collect for "not in".

```
$fixedCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($fixedCategoryId);
$fixedCategoryProductIds = $fixedCategory->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();

...

$collection->addIdFilter($fixedCategoryProductIds, true); // true causes filter to act as an exclude filter
...
```